# Prob with Ruby on codecademy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error

Error message keeps Pooping up on codecademy, and I dont understand why, any help is welcome!

here is my code:

```
  movies={ 
        Lala:3, 
        VV:4 
    } 
    puts "What to do?" 
    choice=gets.chomp

    case choice 
    when "add" 
      puts "What movie you wanna add?" 
      title=gets.chomp 
      if movies[title.to_sym].nil? 
        puts "What rating for the movie?" 
        rating=gets.chomp 
        movies[title.to_sym]=rating.to_i 
        puts "Movie and rating added!" 
      else 
        puts "movie already in list..." 
      end

    when "update" 
      puts "what movie to update?" 
      title=gets.chomp 
      if movies[title.to_sym].nil? 
        puts "Error movie not in list" 
      else 
        puts "New rating?" 
        rating=gets.chomp 
        movies[title.to_sym]=rating.to_i 
        puts "Rating updated" 
      end 

    when "display" 
      movies.each do |movies,rating| 
        puts "#{movies}: #{rating}" 
      end 

    when "delete" 
      puts "Movie to delete?" 
      title = gets.chomp
        if movies[title.to_sym].nil?
            puts "Movie not found"
        else
            movies.delete(title.to_sym)
            puts "Movie deleted"
    end
```

***here is the error message:***

```
(ruby): syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
...     Lala:3,      VV:4  }  puts "What to do?"  choice=gets.c...
...
```

Help! Please! Thanks!!

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. @Ursus added an answer earlier (then deleted it) which I think is still worth asking, so I'll repeat it here: `Lala` and `VV` - are they variables? if not - then you'd need to add `"` to them if they are meant to be strings. If so - then the names of them should start with a lower case letter (eg `lala` and `vv`) because ruby is interpreting them as a Class-name and Constant (respectively) and may be getting confused (because you haven't declared them anywhere)

Comment: Thank you Taryn! I'm not exactly sure as I'm very very new in coding, but as codecademy called them they would be the key to the hash "movies", having for valu "3" and "4". I wrote them also like this "Lala"=>3 (they said it was the same writing it this way or the other way) but it also didn't work.

Comment: `"Lala"` is a string and is very different to `Lala` -> which is definitely a class-name. So I'd definitely use the quotes around it.

Comment: Yes I know, but the website told be that by writing Lala with the ":" after it was the same as writing it like this ": Lala=>3"  thus making it a symbol. In other words from what I understand is that: "Lala"=>3 is the same as :Lala=>3 the same as Lala:3  isn"t that it?

Comment: should be... but it's more prone to bugs-based-on-typos than being more explicit about it...

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one more `end` to your code.

```
movies={ 
    Lala:3, 
    VV:4 
} 

puts "What to do?" 
choice=gets.chomp

case choice 
when "add" 
  puts "What movie you wanna add?" 
  title=gets.chomp 
  if movies[title.to_sym].nil? 
    puts "What rating for the movie?" 
    rating=gets.chomp 
    movies[title.to_sym]=rating.to_i 
    puts "Movie and rating added!" 
  else 
    puts "movie already in list..." 
  end

when "update" 
  puts "what movie to update?" 
  title=gets.chomp 
  if movies[title.to_sym].nil? 
    puts "Error movie not in list" 
  else 
    puts "New rating?" 
    rating=gets.chomp 
    movies[title.to_sym]=rating.to_i 
    puts "Rating updated" 
  end 

when "display" 
  movies.each do |movies,rating| 
    puts "#{movies}: #{rating}" 
  end 

when "delete" 
  puts "Movie to delete?" 
  title = gets.chomp
    if movies[title.to_sym].nil?
        puts "Movie not found"
    else
        movies.delete(title.to_sym)
        puts "Movie deleted"
end
<=# Need an extra `end` here.
```

You did not close out the case statement.

Comment: I did try with another "end" but still didn't worked and posted this message error  "(ruby): syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
...ala"=>3,      "VV"=>4,  }  puts "What to do?"  choice=gets.c...
...  "

Comment: When I copied paste your code it did work, but when I just add "end" on my code it didn't work... maybe its a prob with the website... (did you change anything, except from adding the 2nd "end"?) Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: Could be you have more than one bug :)
You definitely need an end on the end.... but it could also be the string/class-name problem I described as well. Try doing both to your code and seeing what happens.

Comment: I copied your code exactly, and added the `end`, then posted the code to Codeacademy, and it did not have any errors.

Comment: Ok thanks! I think there is a little prob with my account or something. Thanks again though!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a lot of misguided advice here because, apparently, some people are not familiar with the Ruby 1.9 style hash declarations. There is no syntax error in this code in Ruby 1.9 or later. If you're using an antiquated Ruby 1.8.7 you will get errors.

There is a missing `end` statement which you seem to have missed because of your irregular indentation:

```
when "delete" 
  puts "Movie to delete?" 
  title = gets.chomp
    if movies[title.to_sym].nil?
        puts "Movie not found"
    else
        movies.delete(title.to_sym)
        puts "Movie deleted"
    end # Omitted in original
 end
```

It's not clear why that `if` gets an extra level of indentation, but it's clearly missing its own `end`.

Apart from that I've tested your code with Ruby 1.9, which is a severely out of date version of Ruby, and it works. More recent versions have no issue either, like the latest 2.3.1.

The solution to this is to get a version of Ruby that isn't ancient. Ruby 1.8.7 was kept on extended life-support until 2013, but it's dead now. Even Ruby 1.9 is no longer supported for many gems and applications.

If possible, get a current version of Ruby and try your code. It should work.

Note, one problem here is your irregular indentation which makes spotting syntax errors unusually difficult.